# collision detection

Tags: iphone, collision-detection

HI everybody,
how can i carry out "collision detection" in my app,which
just like this: http://www.gskinner.com/blog/assets/CDTest.swf

Give me some advices,,please..

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `CGRectContainsPoint` and `CGRectIntersectsRect`.