# count the number of time of touches

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview, count

I have a game and I want that every time an image(image1) touchs another image(image2) a counter count one, if it touches a second time it becomes two. So it's something that counts. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a collision detection? This link may help... [collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584810/collision-detection/3584860#3584860)

So you may have to write a collision detection method. Then each time it collide, you increment the count.

```
- (BOOL)collisionCheck:(UIImage *)image1 withImage:(UIImage *)image2 {

    return CGRectIntersectsRect(image1.frame, image2.frame);
}

// then in game loop

// code that move the image here

if ([self collisionCheck:image1 withImage:image2] == YES) {

    // code that bounce the image here

    count++;
}
```

Comment: I know how to use collision detection but I want is to count .How can I count the number of time that it collide ?

Comment: The collision method you wrote could return a boolean. Then you just check if yes then increment the variable. Is that help? In your game loop, I think you check for collision every frame.

Comment: ok but can we use then the number of count for something else. Like if count =10 game finish ??

Comment: I think yes, you can. But the above code is very simple and is for rectangle image objects. I don't know if it will be useful for general use.