# How to set up CGRect around the building in google map?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is my first time making my own project for class.
I understand the concept of CGrectmake.
However, my goal is to make CGrect around the building and using gps current location(blue dot) to touch or across the CGrect line will cause hidden annotation to pop up above the building.
Can anyone give me example? The building is about 150ft(L) by 60ft(W). This building location with annotation(lat and long) is +43.082603,-77.68. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually several questions.

You need to understand [collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584810/collision-detection) and you need to convert lat/lon to points and back - see  MKMapView class, convertCoordinate:toPointToView: and other instances methods.